# tcl file copy on linux, permissions errors

Tags: linux, file, permissions, copy, tcl

I am trying to copy a certain file from one destination on my Linux PC to another using tcl. The command I am using is

```
{file copy -force $fileToCopy $destination}
```

However, I do not have the correct permissions to do this. I tried to change the permissions using:

```
{file attributes $fileToCopy -permissions rwxrwxrwx}
```

I got an error message saying that I am unable to change the permissions because I am not the owner. So, I tried to change the owner of the file using

```
{file attributes $fileToCopy -owner ${::tcl_platform(user)}}
```

I received the same error message saying I cannot change the owner because I am not the owner.

How do I get around this problem? Is there some way of running this command under sudo in tcl so that I am able to copy the file?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have *read* permission on the file (and both *read* and *execute* permissions on all the directories containing it up to the root directory) you should be able to `file copy` it. You also *must* have write permission on the destination. (Obviously!) Setting the permissions on a file requires that you be the owner of the file, or root, and setting the ownership of a file requires even more elevated privileges (it's pretty much only ever done by root or by code that is setuid root). Internally, `file copy` tries to copy the these features of the file as well as the contents, but it does not throw an error if it fails.

While it's possible to do setuid work (via the TclX extension's `id` command) this requires a pretty unusual configuration. It's actually much easier to use sudo to launch the Tcl interpreter running as root.

I'm guessing that either you can't read the file, or you can't write to the destination. Check the first with `file readable $fileToCopy` (just to be sure!) and the latter with `file writable $destination`. (Note that these do not give definitive answers due to the potential for race conditions and the arcane strangeness of the `access()` system call with some filesystems. But they're quite indicative of what's going on, what's the real problem.)